# How to convert string elements to integer in a nested list except the first element

Tags: python, list, nested

I have this list :

Input: `Templist = [['Resource', '0', '3', ], ['read', '0', '0', '0']]`

output should be like this

output: `[['Resource', 0, 3, 7], ['read', 0, 0, 5]]`

I want to convert all strings to integer except the 1st element of each list within Templist.

Comment: Where did that `7` and `5` come from? Are they typos?

Comment: The answers gave you what you asked, However just a little advice, if the Templist is not a input and something you created(with appending or else), you should try to add those values as integers from the beginning rather than try to convert them later. If it is a outside data, you don't need to follow this advice.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> [sublist[:1] + [int(x) for x in sublist[1:]] for sublist in Templist]
[['Resource', 0, 3], ['read', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Alternatively, in Python 2 I'd do it with `map`:

```
>>> [sublist[:1] + map(int, sublist[1:]) for sublist in Templist]
[['Resource', 0, 3], ['read', 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm also assuming that the 7 and 5 magically appearing are typos of yours.

Comment: Could use `sublist[:1]`, then you don't need to put `[]` around it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann thanks, I used your suggestion to improve my answer.

Comment: @panchanan ok, please consider accepting any of the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [[head] + list(map(int, tail)) for head, *tail in Templist]
[['Resource', 0, 3], ['read', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or:

```
>>> [item[:1] + list(map(int, item[1:])) for item in Templist]
[['Resource', 0, 3], ['read', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or:

```
>>> [[item.pop(0)] + list(map(int, item)) for item in Templist]
[['Resource', 0, 3], ['read', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: really like the wildcard, really dislike pop in a list comp

Comment: @timgeb I once used `[max(a, b).pop(0) for _ in a+b]`, how do you like that? :-D. But yeah, I agree here it's not so good.

Answer (score 2):

```
newlist = [[int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in sub] for sub in Templist]
```

is, I believe, what you want.  This is assuming that you the `'7'` and `'5'` showing up is because you accidentally left them out of `Templist`.  This will also have no errors if one of the other strings besides the first is not an integer.

Comment: Would you rather have a program that is very easy to understand, but all it does is print "Hello World!" or a program like Gimp written in machine code?  My method is a little less readable, but it does more.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
def processList (aList):
    finalList = []
    for aListEntry in aList:
        finalListEntry = []
        for aListEntry_entry in aListEntry:
            try:
                finalListEntry.append(int(aListEntry_entry)
            except:
                finalListEntry.append(aListEntry_entry)
        finalList.append(finalListEntry)
    return finalList
```